# Problem deserializing in ASP.NET Core .NET 5 with Angular

Tags: angular, entity-framework-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

In my SQL Server database, I have a table `Menus` with the following columns:
MenuId int
Name varchar (50)
FkMenuId int

Where is a menu table with recursion

I created a Web API .NET Core 5 project, and generated the `Scaffold-DbContext` and API Controllers with EF.

I modify the startup.cs in configureservices with:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddCors(opt => opt.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()));
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);
}
```

Model
public partial class Menu
{
public Menu()
{
InverseFkMenu = new HashSet();
}

```
        [Key]
        public short MenuId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("href")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Href { get; set; }
        public bool IsActivo { get; set; }
        public short? FkMenuId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(FkMenuId))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Menu.InverseFkMenu))]
        public virtual Menu FkMenu { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty(nameof(Menu.FkMenu))]
        public virtual ICollection<Menu> InverseFkMenu { get; set; }
    }
```

API
[HttpGet]
return await _context.Menu.ToListAsync();

When executing the project it generates a json in my endpoint that starts with

```
{  "$id": "1",
  "$values": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "menuId": 1,
      "nombre": "Archivo 1",
      "descripcion": "Archivo",
      "icon": "Archivo",
      "href": "/archivo",
      "isActivo": true,
      "fkMenuId": null,
      "fkMenu": null,
      "inverseFkMenu": {
        "$id": "3",
        "$values": [
```

From the angular project how to go through it with `*NgFor` or how to remove `$id`, `$values` ​​and `$ref`.

I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Could you please share the related codes about your web api controller?

Comment: `JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve` is what causes the `$ id` and `$ values` properties to be inserted.  If you don't want them why are you setting them?

Comment: If I don't add JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve
 I get the error A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.

if I do it with AddNewtonsoftJson (options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore); It does the serealization correctly but it generates a front and back json and messy.

Comment: Im not thinking to remove them tho, since they are important value/information for Client side app (Angular) to deserialize them back into a model with objects referencing each other. I do want to keep them but still, I do not know how to desearialize them into meaningful object data. Anyone know there exists any npm packages doing this? or at least something I can use. Or, do I have to write it myself?

Comment: There is an NPM package with an interceptor that handles this: "angular-json-refs-interceptor"